# Why are these keyframes longer?

Tags: keyframes, timeline

I was just wondering if anyone knows why these particular keyframes are longer than the others? I can see that the tips of the yellow lines for keyframe 0 and 16 are green, but I'm not sure why.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are *Grease Pencil* keyframes that are created when drawing with the *Grease Pencil* tool.

You can change the *Dope Sheet* editor mode to *Grease Pencil* from the *Dope Sheet* header menu to view and/or delete these keyframes:

[image]

Alternatively, you can manage the keyframes from the *Grease Pencil Layers* panel in the *3D View* *Properties Shelf* (<kbd>N</kbd>).

Comment: Ah-hah, that's what those are. Thank you. :D